# Problems with Google Sign-in in Unity

Tags: android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, caching, google-signin

I have two problems with Google Sign-in in Unity. (Android app)
Firstly, by documentation I am using `auth.SignOut();` to sign out, after I sign in again it signs me in but no longer asks me which google account I want to be signed in with, it automatically signs me in to the account I already used.

The second issue is the bigger one, when the user doesnt sign out and closes the app, then launches the app again and tries to sign in the sign-in doesnt complete (I only have code when its a success so maybe it ends with fault). Should I add some kind of code to all scenes so when the user destroys the app it should sign out?

It looks to me both issues are related, something must get cached to the phone and I want to find a way to clear that cache on application launch. Anybody has any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, I found the open issue on the GitHub page of the plugin. In Unity `Application.Quit()` does not reset the cache of the sign-in.

The 2 possible solutions:

1. Instead of quiting the application, just push it to the background
2. You have to export the project and open in Android Studio to change the plugin´s onDestroy() method.

Answer (score 0):

> after I sign in again it signs me in but no longer asks me which google account I want to be signed in with, it automatically signs me in to the account I already used

For me issue was solved when I added `GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignOut();` call for the same instance right after signIn. Hope this helps someone:

```
 var signInUser = await GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn();
 GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like what Mol0ko said. Somehow you need to sign in then sign out in order to display the Google account UI again.

But I added `GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignOut();` in `AuthStateChanged`

```
void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (auth.CurrentUser != user)
    {
        bool signedIn = user != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;
        if (!signedIn && user != null)
        {
            .....
        }
        if (signedIn)
        {
            GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignOut();
        }
    }
}
```